# How to do join in different names in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables named `users` and `buys`:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('referral_code')->nullable();
        $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->string('mobile')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}



public function up()
{
    Schema::create('buys', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->bigInteger('product_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I want to do a join on `users.parent_id` and `buys.user_id`. Here is my current query:

```
public function user ()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class);
}
```

My query:

```
$users = Buy::all()->where('parent_id', auth()->user()->id)->latest()->paginate(25);
```

But my query throws this:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'parent_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from buys where parent_id = 2)

Any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: Where is your query code? you just added the relationship.

Comment: where you placed the user method

Comment: Do you want to join `buys.user_id` with `users.parent_id`?

Comment: @zahidhasanemon my query added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making the relationship, Laravel expects that the foreign key name will be the method name + `_id` in your case `user_id` which is okay for the local key, but the foreign key is not the id on the user table, so you need to tell Laravel that. So try this instead:

```
public function user ()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'parent_id', 'user_id');
}
```

-- EDIT after seeing your query

You are trying to use a column that does not exist on your buys model.

```
$users = Buy::with('user')->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->latest()->paginate(25);
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be like

```
$users = Buy::where('user_id', auth()->user()->parent_id)->latest()->paginate(25);
```